# Density function and expected value

Tags: probability, integration, discrete-mathematics, definite-integrals, expectation

> The density function of $X$ is given by: $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
>  a+bx^2 & 0\le x\le 1\\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{matrix}\right.$$ If
>    $E[X] = \frac{3}{5}$, find $a$ and $b$.

I'm not really sure how to do this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You have two equations :

$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx=1,\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^1 xf(x)dx=3/5$$

The first one because $f$ must be a density of probability, and the second one is given to you.
Express those two integrals in terms of $a$ and $b$ and you will have a system with two equations and two unknowns.

Comment: So is the first one $\int_{0}^{1}{a+bx^2}dx$?

Comment: Yes, now integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

One may recall that, for any density $f$, we have
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\:dx=1
$$ giving here
$$
\int_0^1 (a+bx^2)\:dx=1
$$ or

> $$
> a+\frac{b}3=1. \tag1
> $$

On the other hand, we know that
$$
E(X)=\int_0^\infty x \times f(x)\:dx=\frac35
$$ which reads
$$
\int_0^1 x(a+bx^2)\:dx=\frac35
$$ or

> $$
> \frac{a}2+\frac{b}4=\frac35. \tag2
> $$

You can then easily conclude.

Comment: So $a = \frac{3}{5}$ and $b = \frac{6}{5}$

Comment: @HallowPer Exactely.